# Intellij IDEA "Decompiled.class file, bytecodeversion:52.0 (Java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to Java, I started to use it a year ago.

I was using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, but I decided to install the full version of it, and then something went wrong. It always stays in kind of "Decompiled" mode and does not allow to edit file or work with it. I reverted back to the Community Edition, but the problem did not disappear.

Can you please help me how to get to normal mode to work? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It looks like you're opening the class files within the left hand navigation window. Find the source code instead (the `.java` files) and open those instead - then everything should be normal.

(Look at `home05\Solution.java` for example, instead of `home05\Solution.class`...)

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!Spent 30 min searching web, going through all setting.... But answer like always was easy

Comment: i ma facing an issue whenever i try to android's class that is extended its showing decompiled .class not .java class but on my other computer its opening .java is there any option to disable this i want to view source please help

Comment: @MateenChaudhry: My *guess* is that the source code isn't available on one of those machines, but I really don't know for sure. I suggest you ask a new question with more details.

Comment: i asked here please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942816/android-studio-shoiwng-decompiled-class-not-java-class

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the "src" folder and not the "out" folder. The out folder in intellij shows the decompile version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

> In Intellij you need src, not out.
> Example is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuBsC.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.