# Android studio showing decompiled class not java class

Tags: android-studio

My `KeyboardView` was opening fine and whenever I click on this extended class it was showing `.java` class but I tried to edit this class and there were options to edit for this session. After that whenever I click on this `KeyboardView` extended class it's not showing java class it's only showing .class. How can I resolve this problem?
[image]

**EDIT**

there were these option and i selected the first one
after that this happened

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows the `KeyboardView` class provided by Android, not your subclass. I wouldn't *expect* you to be able to edit that. Where exactly did you click to show that?

Comment: there was option like "for this session" and after that its not showing java is there any option in android studio to show decompiled class or java class?

Comment: You didn't answer address any of the points I made - and I'm sure "for this session" isn't the full name of the option. Please try to be a lot clearer in your description of what you're doing and seeing. Regardless of whether or not the decompiled class is shown, you're not going to be able to change `KeyboardView` itself, as that's a system-provided class.

Comment: please check edited question

Comment: Okay, so that should be a red flag to start with - it's warning you that basically you can't *really* change this class. It's not clear what you're attempting to achieve, but you shouldn't be trying to modify the Android system classes.

Comment: So what should i do to show java class again?

Comment: Take a step back: ask yourself what benefit there is in showing a .java file that you can edit rather than a decompiled class file, when you can't *really* change either of them. (But beyond that, I won't know the answer - I don't do Android development or use IDEA.)

Comment: ok i am gonna reinstall android studio it then i will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by installing new sdk